# Why is this analytics event tracking code not working?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

My website offers downloads of various apps for Windows, Mac, and Linux platforms. I want to count the number of times each individual software package is downloaded. I believe this is accomplished in Google Analytics by setting up event tracking code.

I have this Javascript code at the top of my page:

```
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;I have this m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)


  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

  // Necessary for the download tracking code to work.
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

Downloads are selected via a dropdown menu, which points to Javascript code that gets the right package for download, and triggers an Analytics tracking event.

The code attached to each downloadable app looks like this:

```
if (packageChoice === "App1")
{
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'App1 Name']);
    window.open("/download/app1.exe");
}
else if (packageChoice === "App2")
{
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'App2 Name']);
    window.open("/download/app2.pkg");
}
```

However, I have not registered a single download in Google Analytics/Behaviour/Events.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing `_gaq.push` (which is from old `ga.js`) and `ga.send` which is from `analytics.js` which you are using.

Instead of:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'App2 Name']);
```

try:

```
ga('send' , 'event', 'Downloads', 'App2 Name');
```

Documentation:

- [For legacy (ga.js)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApi_gaq#push)
- [For analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)

Comment: Thank you for responding. If this is the case, then is the part of my header code that says `var _gaq = _gaq || [];` necessary?

Comment: No, not at all... that'd be doing the same as the  `ga('create',...` and `ga('send', 'pageview');` in the legacy `ga.js` style. In fact, if you didn't use `var _gaq = _gaq || [];` you'd see that probably `_gaq` is not defined (I haven't tried, but I suspect so), so that code is doing nothing

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've updated my code. Nothing seems to have changed in the Analytics "real time" interface, but that may not mean anything. I'll wait a day or so and see if anything changes in the Analytics/Behaviour/Events section.

Comment: @Questioner you may want (if you use Chrome) to use the developer console (F12) and check if there are errors in the console, and check the `Network` tab to see if the event is being passed to GA (open the developer console while on your site, set the `Network` tab and generate an event on your page). Events should definitely appear in the `realtime` panel. Notice that most adblockers block google analytics, so if you use one in your browser, you may want to disable it